# "Closed-form" expression for CDF for a bivariate normal distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

Is there any way to recover a "closed-form-expression" for the cdf of a bivariate normal distribution?

What I have in mind is the following: for a univariate standard normal, we can write $$\text{Pr}(X\leq x)=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(1+\text{erf}\left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$
in terms of the error function.

When doing the same exercise with a bivariate standard normal with a correlation of, say, $\rho=1/2$, I find that (with $f(x,y)$ being the joint density)
$$\int_{-\infty}^{y}f(t,s)\,ds=\dfrac{\exp\left(-\dfrac{t^2}{2}\right)\left(1-\text{erf}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{6}t}{6}-\dfrac{\sqrt{6}y}{3}\right)\right)}{2\sqrt{2}\pi}$$
such that recovering
$$\text{Pr}(X\leq x,Y\leq y)=\int_{-\infty}^x\int_{-\infty}^yf(t,s)\,ds\,dt$$
involves an integration over
$$\exp\left(-\dfrac{t^2}{2}\right)\left(1-\text{erf}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{6}t}{6}-\dfrac{\sqrt{6}y}{3}\right)\right)$$
where I have absolutely no idea how to tackle that. Is there any way to write $\text{Pr}(X\leq x , Y\leq y)$ in terms of error- or other well-known functions?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) "Though there is no closed form for $ F ( x )$, there are a number of algorithms that estimate it numerically"

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. As I do know that there are people who do not think of the error function as a closed-form, I have been hoping that there might be an expression that is not strictly speaking closed-form but makes use of something along the lines of an error-function

Comment: It's not closed form but here's a nice formula:
$
  \Pr\left(X\le h, Y \le k\right) =
  \Phi(h)\Phi(k)+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\arcsin \rho}\exp\left(-\frac{h^{2}+k^{2}-2hk\sin\theta}{2\cos^{2}\theta}\right)d\theta
$

where
$ \Phi(h)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{h}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$.
http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/genz/papers/bvnt.pdf

Comment: Thanks. That is really helpful. Considerably sped up the computation...